# Problema al generar Signed APK en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de generar el Signed APK en android studio pero me manda el siguiente error cada vez que lo intento:

```
Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Mi build.gradle tiene el siguiente código:

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edu.paquete.ejemplo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

  dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'Codeview-1.0.0:webviewcode:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Al momento de mirar cual es el error es este el que me muetra:

```
 Java compiler (109 warnings)
```

Comment: no estas diciendo nada, cuales son las advertencias que te tira????? sin eso como te ayudamos, pues hay un sin fin de motivos por los cuales no te compila, a ciegas es imposible

Comment: Debes ser especifico y aportar información decir que tienes un error o advertencia implica miles de causas, te sugiero revisar [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace algún tiempo tuve el mismo error, en mi caso fue  por dejar la propiedad `minifyEnabled=true`, para utilizar `proguard`. Tienes que configurar bien el archivo *proguard-android.txt*, en Internet hay algunos tutoriales, pero para asegurarte de que el problema es el que te digo, deja *minifyEnabled* en `false`.

Comment: El usuario no especifica el problema que se muestra. No especifica cuales son los warnings.